# Show download progresstext while file download in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am developing an app using Angularjs and Cordova in which there is feature for  download files from a list of files,while downloading i am showing a progress text  to show the status of the download.

Here is my code

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="result in results">
<button ng-click="downloadVideo(result.file_url)">Download</button>
<!--for showing download status-->
<span ng-show="status">{{progress}}</span>
</div>
```

In my controller

```
.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
   /* get json link of the video files
   $http.get(url).then(function(data){
        $scope.results=data;
      },function(err){
        console.log("Can't connect to server,check connection url");
      });
/*--for downloading videos--*/   
$scope.downloadVideo=function(url){ 

 $scope.progress='20% downloaded';
}
```

The problem is when i click on download a button all the `span` shows the download progress text,but i want to show only the one `span` with the progress text not the entire span.

Comment: Wrap the button and span in a div and display information accordingly i.e. the information about each video should be kept separately as an array.

Answer (score 1):

you should bind your `progress` property to each result, instead of directly having it on `scope`.
like:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="result in results">
<button ng-click="downloadVideo(result)">Download</button>
<!--for showing download status-->
<span ng-show="status">{{result.progress}}</span>
</div>

$scope.downloadVideo=function(result){ 
 url = result.file_url;
result.progress = '20% download';

}
```

Comment: It's worked,but I want to achive another thing ,when click on download button hide the button and shows progress text after completing download shows button.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store the progress of each video i.e.

```
/*controller*/
$scope.progress = [] ;

$scope.downloadVideo = function(url, index) {
    $scope.progress[index] = 'some %';
    ...
};

$scope.displayProgress = function(index) {
    if($scope.progress[index] > 0)
        return $scope.progress[index] + ' % downloaded' ;
    else
        return '' ;
};
```

And then in the HTML,

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="result in results">
<button ng-click="downloadVideo(result.file_url, $index)">Download</button>
<!--for showing download status-->
<span ng-show="status">{{displayProgress($index)}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML file :

```
<script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
</script>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary margin rightmargin "
        ng-click="tableToExcel()">Download Data</button>
</body>
```

abc.js file :

```
//copy all data of database to excelsheet
$scope.tableToExcel = function () {

    $("#table2Id").table2excel({
        filename: "Table.xls"
    });
}
```